# MYSQL - Select Query Between DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a booking in my mysql booking table `bookings` as below:

```
start_date = 2013-03-04
end_date = 2013-03-08
```

I want to check if a particular day (in this case 2013-03-04) falls between the start and end dates in the booking(s) - BUT i want to add one day to the start date and subtract 1 day from the end date.

So instead of searching between 2013-03-**04** and 2013-03-**08**
i want to search between 2013-03-**05** and 2013-03-**07**

The following query below does the subtract 1 day from the end date but keeps the start date as 04. The search below should give no results but it is still using 04 as the start date and giving my the result of that booking. It is basically searching between [04] [05] [06] [07] when it should do [05] [06] [07]

```
$fd_query_params = array( 
    ':day' => '2013-03-04
);

$query = " 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        bookings as bb 
    WHERE 
        :day BETWEEN 
        DATE_ADD(bb.start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        AND 
        DATE_SUB(bb.end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not php expert myself but should there be more than I notice there is only a single quote around the :day  string. It would be good to see the output to verify what the start_date and end_date is